# How to make the opacity of box-shadow exclusive to the shadow and not the div

Tags: html, css

This is my code

```
.navbar {
width: 100%;
height: 70px;
position: fixed;
background-color: white;
box-shadow: 0 0 1em #1d1d1d;    
}
```

Every time I run something under this e.g. something that has a background color the shadow goes under it and so does the rest of the content.
Should I just  layer it?

Comment: Post your HTML too.

Comment: '<div class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><p>Home</p></li>
            <li><p>Products</p></li>
            <li><p>About</p></li>
            <li><p>Contacts</p></li>
        </ul>
    </div>' cant seem to get this into a code format sorry

Comment: It works as it should... what's exactly your desidered behevour?

Comment: The background content was going through the code but now I have added 'z-index' and added values its all good.

Comment: google "css box shadow generator"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you have, this should work. I think there is a possibility two things are happening here:

1. Check if you are setting the z-index on the elements that are going above your fixed nav to a greater value or you could set a `z-index` value on `.navbar` to see if that helps.
2. The other possibility is that you are setting the elements that are overlapping your `.navbar` to `absolute`. If that is the case, and this is necessary, you could set the `z-index` on `.navbar` to a greater value.

Hope that helps.